# Open source project management software similar to Fogbugz?

Tags: project-management, issue-tracking

I'm looking for an open-source project management and issue-tracking tool with features similar to Fogbugz, well, specifically with a clean, easy to use UI.

I've been looking around but can't seem to find a similar tool.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT:

I've just seen OpenAtrium - has anyone any experience of using it. What's it like?

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836493/cheaper-alternative-to-fogbugz

Comment: One has to cringe if the feature that defines a particular software is 'a clean, easy to use UI'. Do we enjoy having to work poorly?

Comment: Have you seen some of the alternatives?

Comment: No, I mean exactly that, the fact that the alternatives don't have a clean, easy to use UI and that FogBugz is almost synonymous with it is what depresses me. It's not a slight on FogBugz, it's a slight on the other bug tracking apps.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [*Launchpad*](http://launchpad.net/), a popular code and project management tool known for its use by Ubuntu. You can either put your project on their website, or, if you prefer to keep the project on your own computer(s), [get Launchpad](https://dev.launchpad.net/Getting) and install it. It's open source.

Comment: is it difficult to run on a non-Ubuntu linux (specificially CentOS)?

Comment: well, the linked page about 'getting' says "right now, Launchpad can only be built and run on Ubuntu Hardy, Jaunty, Karmic or Lucid (*). That's not a design decision, it's just a consequence of the fact that, until now, all its developers have been running Ubuntu."

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the software listed on the [Project Management Open Source Software Directory](http://www.opensourceprojectmanagement.org/) ?